# Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, sandbox, production

I am developing a application for IOS 8, 9 and 10, which should receive push notifications.

The certificate for push notifications has been created by using the option “Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)”, but unfortunately when I try to receive the push notification from the Sandbox environment, the notification I'm getting.

In particular, what I do is this.

1. Generate Push Certificate with the following option to the “Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)”
2. Start XCode
3. I connect the device (iPod IOS 9.3.5) to the Macbook Pro.
4. The startup project d XCode.
5. NSLog("tokenString: (tokenString)")
6. The device token is successfully registered.
7. Sending the notification from the Java class, but unfortunately, the push notification I don't receive it

If, instead, generate, the ipa (XC Ad Hoc), and then I install everything through iTunes, the device token is successfully registered and when I send the push notification from the same Java class with the same Certificate, the push notification i receive it.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The ad-hoc ipa build is a production build, if pushes are successfully getting sent to that then means that your "the Java class (sic)" is sending the pushes using the production certificate over the production environment.

When you build and run the app via Xcode then the app is being built in development mode, so you need to switch your "the Java class" to use the development certificate and to send the push over the development environment. The url for the development environment is gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

P.S.
The Xcode build scheme can be changed to produce a production build instead of a debug build, but you want to be able to debug your apps don't you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think that certificate is generate is not correct. Whick is the different between "Apple Push Notification service SSL (sandbox)" and "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)”  ?

Comment: I think that option is new as I've not seen it before, but it specifically mentions HTTP/2. Is your server/network HTTP/2, if not better stick with generating dev and prod separately, even if you have two certificates you can still sign your server with both simultaneously.

Comment: Ok...tomorrow i create certificate only for sandbox and try send push notification

Comment: This morning I fired again, the certificate, but I generated the “Apple Push Notification service SSL (sandbox)” and then with the device connected to the USB port of the Macbook Pro, I received the push notification.
Thank you all for the support